# HTML Printing: DOT-MATRIX

Tags: html, css, printing, dot-matrix

I'm printing an HTML receipt via `javascript:window.print()`

Printing it to an Inkjet Printer makes everything all good. However on DOT-MATRIX Printer, Epson LX-300+II everything is different. It doesn't fit right, the texts are not aligned. I tried saving it to PDF and printing the PDF from Adobe Reader, the orientation seemed to be all good.

I already set the page size and tried resizing the fonts, but still I can't print it correctly. The Receipt's size, by the way, is **8.5 x 5.5in**.

I tried formulating the CSS, but failed to get the correct result.
This is the CSS:

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 5.5in;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    font-size: auto;
  }

  @page
   {
    size: 5.5in 8.5in;
  }

}
```

Also whenever I tried adding `@page { size: 8.5in 5.5in.; size: Portrait; }` the printed paper is on landscape.

How can I set things right?

**EDIT:**
I tried

```
@page {
    size: 5.5in 8.5in;
}
```

but it's printing the page on Landscape...

Comment: I had this exact same issue, it turns out (despite what people say), it doesn't seem to be possible. The best thing to do is the `@media print{ /*hide what you don't need/clutter*/ }` and add this where it is needed as a "print.css" file

Comment: a width of 8.5 inches and a height of 5.5 inches is landscape. are you sure you don't have those values reversed?

Comment: Print it using internet explore or other browser, I hope it will work

Comment: @Leroy I have to edit my post. I forgot something

Comment: @SamSwift Actually, I have to print the whole page since the HTML is already printable, and I have removed all the unnecessary parts.

Comment: @AaronAlfonso, try switching your `8.5in` with `5.5in`, as Leroy said - **a width of 8.5 inches and a height of 5.5 inches is landscape**

Comment: So `size: width height` ?

Comment: @AaronAlfonso, please see my [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142743/html-printing-dot-matrix/32142993#32142993]

Comment: check out my answer. I managed it to fix it

Answer (score 6):

**Solved the Problem!**

In my Printer(LX-300-II), I defined a Paper Size which width is 8.5in and 5.5in in height. There is also a change in CSS Code:

```
 @media print {
    html, body {
        display: block; 
        font-family: "Calibri";
        margin: 0;
    }

    @page {
      size: 21.59cm 13.97cm;
    }

    .logo {
      width: 30%;
    }

}
```

Since I have images in my Receipt, I made some width adjustments to fit it just right.

I hope this can help those people who is encountering this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the size and height the wrong way around in `@media print`, try this:

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 5.5in; /* was 8.5in */
        height: 8.5in; /* was 5.5in */
        display: block;
        font-family: "Calibri";
        /*font-size: auto; NOT A VALID PROPERTY */
    }

    @page {
        size: 5.5in 8.5in /* . Random dot? */;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Gonna check it out.  That `dot` seemed to be drunk. lol

Comment: @AaronAlfonso, I cannot guarantee this will/will not work, It is just a starter idea

Comment: it's printed in Landscape... :/

Comment: Didn't think that it would, but it was worth a jolly good go!

Answer (score 0):

This Problem may come based on the Browser setup or Paper size setup. Check your browser font setting and paper size in printing properties.